# Understanding wadl file of rest service

Tags: xml, rest, httpwebrequest

I've searched around but I don't really know how to interpret the wadl file of the rest service I have to use. (wadl included at bottom..)

Like I thought simple GET request like this should work:

```
http://<IP HERE>:8080/RestZone-it/resources/be.zonit.rest.data?plaats=<SOME LOCATION>
```

(Dutch -> English)
plaats = location

But it doesn't work, I still get all the data..
Could someone explain how to use the service? (A bit more then simply telling me how to do this single request would be appreciated ^^ )

```
<application xmlns="http://research.sun.com/wadl/2006/10">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM"/>
    <resources base="http://<IP-HERE>:8080/RestZone-it/resources/">
        <resource path="be.zonit.rest.data">
            <method id="create" name="POST">
                <request>
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                </request>
            </method>
            <method id="findAll" name="GET">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                </response>
            </method>
            <method id="edit" name="PUT">
                <request>
                <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                </request>
            </method>
            <resource path="{id}">
                <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="id" style="template" type="xs:int"/>
                <method id="find" name="GET">
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
                <method id="remove" name="DELETE"/>
            </resource>
            <resource path="count">
                <method id="countREST" name="GET">
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
            <resource path="{from}/{to}">
                <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="to" style="template" type="xs:int"/>
                <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="from" style="template" type="xs:int"/>
                <method id="findRange" name="GET">
                    <response>
                        <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                        <representation mediaType="application/json"/>
                    </response>
                </method>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

Example of response

```
<data>
    <aantalDeelnemers>50</aantalDeelnemers>
    <begin>15:30</begin>
    <datum>5/07/2012</datum>
    <einde>1:00</einde>
    <gemeente>Gent</gemeente>
    <huisnr>2</huisnr>
    <id>1</id>
    <indoor>0</indoor>
    <omschrijving>
    Gent Jazz Festival vindt dit jaar plaats van 5 t.e.m. 14 juli in de tuinen van De Bijloke in Gent.
    </omschrijving>
    <ownerID>1</ownerID>
    <plaats>Bijlokesite</plaats>
    <straat>Godshuizenlaan</straat>
    <titel>Gent Jazz Festival</titel>
</data>
```

Comment: There is nothing about "*plaats*" parameter in WADL, why do you believe it should work and is not simply ignored?

Comment: Since rest is a framework I thought that this would be basic functionality to filter on parameters that are in the rest database. I'll edit my post now to show an example response. (sorry I forgot that and made things a bit 'unclear'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this URL:

```
 http://<IP HERE>:8080/RestZone-it/resources/be.zonit.rest.data/<SOME LOCATION>
```

Comment: I don't think that works.. as far as I know when using rest, the 'resources' like: <resource path="{from}/{to}"> are stuff you can put behind the ....data/ so using what you suggested just gives a 404 since it isn't specified to reply to that.

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/ it looks like my suggestion is correction.  Ensure <SOME LOCATION> is an integer and is a valid ID.  The WADL specifies ID is an integer, but it seems you want to specify a plaats (string?).  There is no resource template for looking up plaats directly.